# What is the mechanism of the blades movement

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

[image]

this is deblistering machine by Stripfoil. I wounder to know the mechanism of blades movement ( equally ) with `one?` screw. when the operator rotates the handle, all blades move with the same distance.

Comment: A set of cams...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by a series of 4 bar linkages

[image]

The above is used for marking out equally spaced points on a line of arbitrary length.

Pretty simple and elegant. By virtue of the geometry you can choose any two points as the start and end and the distance between them will always be equal fractions of the total.

Obviously in this particular context you would need some extra parts to implement it properly and maybe make the whole thing a bit stiffer, but within  reasonable range of adjustment it should do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: We have a winner. Almost assuredly the right answer.

Comment: @EricShain of course it is.

Comment: Its probably a variant of this though where the bottom links are replaced by a slider.